# Add new Key/Value into Object in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-native, addition

I'm working on a React Native project. Right now, I'm adding new key/value inside an object.

It's working but I would like to know if there is a better way to do it or if you have any advice.

I'm still new to ReactJS/React Native and not 100% skills on Javascript. So here's my code :

**My object**

```
state = {
    result : {
        "q1":1
    }
}
```

**My function** to add key/value and modify the state of `result` :

```
_getValue = (id, value) => {

    var newObj = this.state.result;
        newObj[id] = parseInt(value);

    this.setState({
        result: newObj
    }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.result)
    })
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: What you did is good. The only change I would recommend is change var to const :) and this.state.result; assign state as const { result } = this.state; instead of calling this.state everytime

Comment: it is not - he is mutating the state.result directly before calling setState which is not synchronous. it *may* cause an unexpected bug that is very hard to catch.

Comment: @Dimitar he is adding new key and value to the existing object. Isnt it? What’s wrong in that?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state - the issue is also (potentially) in that something else may be causing render meanwhile before the queued `setState()` change takes effect (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate - it shows how it may not do it immediately, batch it of defer it for later). so other parts of the app may get the changed values before they should. it's acceptable to do `const  result = Object.assign({}, this.state.result);` to avoid mutating it directly (or spread).

Comment: @Think-Twice he changes in place existing object, that changes, but replaces immutably part that didn't change. This makes no sense. And setState should be immutable update.

Comment: @Think-Twice oh yeah you're right ! My mistake :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this should work fine.

```
this.setState({
  result: {
     ...this.state.result,
     [id]: value
  }
});
```

it uses modern/new features such as object spread (`...this.state.result`) and dynamic object properties (`[id]: value`)

Comment: Thank you ! I got it about the immutable state. I don't know why I did this ... I did the right thing in another component but I completely forgot :-)